# conexion remota a SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql, windows, ssms

Tengo un inconveniente al conectarme de forma remota a SQL Server. Tengo lo siguiente:

- Un servidor Windows 2012 R2, con SSMS 2017, y con SQL Express Edition.
- Una base de datos, llamada Test, y la instancia es SQLExpress.
- También tengo habilitado el acceso remoto, los puertos 1433-1434, y adicional me cree un usuario con permisos para poder acceder.

> Desde un equipo externo, me trato de conectar desde un SSMS y no me
>   encuentra el servidor remoto de SQL; tampoco puedo hacer un test,
>   desde panel de control/odbc.

¿Faltará abrir algún puerto? Los dos puertos anteriores los tengo abiertos, tanto en el windows server como en el firewall propiamente.

Comment: configuraste al usuario que tiene acceso a la conexion remota?

Comment: telnet a la IP del servidor por el 1433 funciona o da timeout?

Comment: No se puede abrir la conexion al host, en puerto 1433. Error en la conexion.

Answer (score -1):

**Para configurar la opción de acceso remoto**

1. En el Explorador de objetos, haga clic derecho en un servidor y
   seleccione Propiedades.
2. Haga clic en el nodo Conexiones.
3. En Conexiones del servidor remoto , active o desactive la casilla de
   verificación Permitir conexiones remotas a este servidor.

Te comparto un enlace de referencia :

[Configuración Acceso Remoto SQL Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-remote-access-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-2017#SSMSProcedure)

Comment: Así lo tengo colocado

Comment: Esto está en una LAN o CLOUD ??

Comment: El tema está en que tal y como está ahora mismo, tenemos un 'server' con la base de datos y contrataron un servicio en nube (que sera en un servidor local - no en nube), y por lo tanto me toca migrar la base de datos a ese nuevo servidor y apuntar el programa a la nueva ip

Comment: Entonces es una conexión CLOUD; en el SSMS para el nombre del servidor usas ip publica o un dominio ??

Comment: Uso ip pública, y usando el dominio, el resultado es el mismo.

Comment: A pesar de todas las pruebas, aún no me he podido conectar. Estoy seguro que es un tema de puertos, firewall, tcp/udp, puertos dinámicos. ¿Alguna sugerencia adicional?